# if there is not key and value pair in list then skip this data using python

Tags: python, list, split

I have list of data that contains the key and values data but some time it contains only data. I want to skip this type of data.

I got the below error:-

Example :-

```
formatted_desc_split = ['Akshay Godase is from pune', 'Amar:Satara', 'Sandesh:Solapur', 'Mahesh:Nagpur', 'Prashant:Indapur']

for each_split_data in formatted_desc_split:
    split_by_colon = each_split_data.split(":")
```

```
Error :-
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I want to skip `Akshay Godase is from pune` data. if there is not key and value pair in list then i want to skip this data. I am not able to split this data because in first index there is not key values paire.

How can i solve the above proble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehensions. Concise, readable, pythonic:

```
>>> strings = ['Akshay Godase is from pune', 'Amar:Satara', 'Sandesh:Solapur', 'Mahesh:Nagpur', 'Prashant:Indapur']
>>> [s for s in strings if ':' in s]
['Amar:Satara', 'Sandesh:Solapur', 'Mahesh:Nagpur', 'Prashant:Indapur']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following instead:

```
formatted_desc_split = ['Akshay Godase is from pune', 'Amar:Satara', 'Sandesh:Solapur', 'Mahesh:Nagpur', 'Prashant:Indapur']

for each_split_data in formatted_desc_split:
    if ":" not in each_split_data:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

May not be an elegant way, but the following code does what you wanted. Just for the sake of an alternative solution.

```
formatted_desc_split = ['Akshay Godase is from pune', 'Amar:Satara', 'Sandesh:Solapur', 'Mahesh:Nagpur', 'Prashant:Indapur']

my_dict = {}

for each_split_data in formatted_desc_split:
    split_by_colon = each_split_data.split(":")
    if len(split_by_colon) == 2:
        my_dict[split_by_colon[0]] = split_by_colon[1]
    print(my_dict)
```